# How can I remove certain characters in a text file and create a line in between them in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to turn

```
['player3 has won with 22 cards', 'player2 has won with 20 cards', 'player9 has won with 20 cards', 'player4 has won with 18 cards', 'player5 has won with 18 cards']
```

Into

```
player3 has won with 22 cards
player2 has won with 20 cards
player9 has won with 20 cards
player4 has won with 18 cards
player5 has won with 18 cards
```

I tried using the replace function however while the program didn't return an error, it did nothing.

```
replacer = str(blockoftext).replace(",","")
```

So how could I do this?

Comment: Assuming `blockoftext` in your last code snippet has the value shown in your first snippet, its not a "block" of text. It's a list of strings. What do you mean by "turn it into"? Are you trying to print that out? Write it to a file? Something else?

Comment: `'\n'.join(your_list)`

Comment: Is your input is LIST or a STRING format?

Comment: Did you mean: ‘for line in blockoftext: print(line)’?

Comment: @Chris Yes it is I can't think of good variables. I mean I need to write it into a text file.

Comment: This didn't work @dawg. It didn't return an error but it did nothing.

Comment: What do you need to turn it into? A list? A string? Or something else? dawg solution is correct given your explanation. If it didn't do anything, the it's because you didn't do anything with it. But it will give you a string on the format you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

```py
replacer = '\n'.join(
    [
        'player3 has won with 22 cards', 
        'player2 has won with 20 cards', 
        'player9 has won with 20 cards', 
        'player4 has won with 18 cards', 
        'player5 has won with 18 cards'
    ]
)

print(replacer)

# write it into a file
print(replacer, file=open("test.txt", "w+"))
```

Here, using the [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) you're joining the list of items using `'\n'` (newline) character.

Comment: The join combines all elements of the given list and seperates them with the new line "\n"

Comment: @dallavid from the comments I got to know that you want to write the output into a file. So I updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the text into a list of strings, and then join that into a string separated by newlines.

```
import ast

blockoftext = "['player3 has won with 22 cards', 'player2 has won with 20 cards', 'player9 has won with 20 cards', 'player4 has won with 18 cards', 'player5 has won with 18 cards']"
string_list = ast.literal_eval(blockoftext)
lines = "\n".join(string_list)
print(lines)
```